# How to sort JSON object in javascript based on sys_created_on date in descending order so that most recently created data shows up first

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, data-structures

I need to sort JSON object based on created date in descending order so that most recently created date data shows first.

```
var Array = {
"result": {
  "items": [
    {
      "content_sys_id": "10999ec787941d10f2d740c8dabb3503",
      "sys_created_on": "2022-08-06 12:08:09"
    },
    {
      "content_sys_id": "730e2e9547b0d110fa462034846d432a",
      "sys_created_on": "2022-08-06 12:08:23"
    },
    {
      "content_sys_id": "008f0a2b87dc5d10f2d740c8dabb35a0",
      "sys_created_on": "2022-08-02 02:22:20"
    },
    {
      "content_sys_id": "002301478788d15038a740c8dabb350e",
      "sys_created_on": "2022-08-07 17:28:42"
    },
    {
      "content_sys_id": "cb895ec787941d10f2d740c8dabb357e",
      "sys_created_on": "2022-08-11 23:34:08"
    }
  ],
  "count": 5,
  "total_records": "5",
  "offset": 500,
  "has_more": false
}
};

var sortedArray = Array.sort(function(a, b){
var x = a.items.sys_created_on;
var y = b.items.sys_created_on;
return x < y ? -1 : x > y ? 1 : 0;
//return y - x;
//return new Date(b.items.sys_created_on) - new Date(a.items.sys_created_on);
  });
console.log("sorted array :: " + JSON.stringify(sortedArray)); //getting output as sorted array :: undefined
}
```

i tried above solutions but no luck so far.  Please suggest the solution.

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort an object array by date property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123953/how-to-sort-an-object-array-by-date-property)

Comment: I tried below scripts but didn't got the solution: 

  var sortedArray = Array.sort(function(a, b){
  var x = a.result.items.sys_created_on;
  var y = b.result.items.sys_created_on;
  return x < y ? -1 : x > y ? 1 : 0;
  //return y - x;
  });
  console.log("sorted array :: " + JSON.stringify(sortedArray));
  }

Getting output as sorted array :: undefined
Please suggest the solution.

Comment: As sort is work on arrays. Hence, it should be `Array.results.items.sort` instead of `Array.sort` as `Array` is an object not an array as per your JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this works, take in account the fallowing recomendations

1. Yo must apply sort method to an array in this case Array.result.items not to Array becouse this is an object
2. Before compare dates you need to convert them to a Date type.

I hope it could be helpful

```
    var Array = {
"result": {
  "items": [
    {
      "content_sys_id": "10999ec787941d10f2d740c8dabb3503",
      "sys_created_on": "2022-08-06 12:08:09"
    },
    {
      "content_sys_id": "730e2e9547b0d110fa462034846d432a",
      "sys_created_on": "2022-08-06 12:08:23"
    },
    {
      "content_sys_id": "008f0a2b87dc5d10f2d740c8dabb35a0",
      "sys_created_on": "2022-08-02 02:22:20"
    },
    {
      "content_sys_id": "002301478788d15038a740c8dabb350e",
      "sys_created_on": "2022-08-07 17:28:42"
    },
    {
      "content_sys_id": "cb895ec787941d10f2d740c8dabb357e",
      "sys_created_on": "2022-08-11 23:34:08"
    }
  ],
  "count": 5,
  "total_records": "5",
  "offset": 500,
  "has_more": false
}
};

let sortedItems = Array.result.items.sort((a,b)=>{
    let aDate = new Date(a.sys_created_on);
    let bDate = new Date(b.sys_created_on);
    return bDate - aDate;
});

Array.result.items = sortedItems;

console.log(Array.result.items);
```

Comment: This helped build my solution

Answer (score 0):

I got my working solution:

```js
var resultSorted = Array.result.items.sort(function(a, b) {
var x = a.sys_created_on;
var y = b.sys_created_on;
return x > y ? -1 : x < y ? 1 : 0;
});
```